# Error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table for user and my columns are `User_Id`, `User_Pass`, `User_Type`.

After I saved this table, I created a stored procedure and successfully ran a query. But after connecting from C#, I get an error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'UserPassChek'

Data access code:

```
namespace Salse_Mangment_System.Dal
{
    class DataAccessLayer
    {
        SqlConnection cn;

        public DataAccessLayer()
        {
            cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = DESKTOP-OH8J8IE; Initial Catalog = libarty_DB; Integrated Security = true");
        }

        // Method To Open cn
        public void Open()
        {
            if(cn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cn.Open();
            }
        }

        // method To Close Cn
        public void Close()
        {
            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }

        // method To read data from database
        public DataTable selectdata (string store_prosudre , SqlParameter [] param)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = store_prosudre;
            cmd.Connection = cn;

            if (param != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
                }
            }

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            return dt; 
        }

        // method to insert delete update data 
        public void Executecommand(string store_procdure , SqlParameter [] param)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType= CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = store_procdure;
            cmd.Connection = cn;

            if (param != null)
            {
               cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

and class `logincls` is

```
class Logincls
{
    // make function to cheek login procedure
    public DataTable login(string ID,string Pwd)
    {
        Dal.DataAccessLayer dal = new Dal.DataAccessLayer();

        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@IDUser", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        param[0].Value = ID;
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@PasUser", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        param[1].Value = Pwd;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dal.Open();
        dt = dal.selectdata("UserPassChek", param);

        return dt;  
    }
}
```

Login form:

```
public class FrmLogin
{
    Bl.Logincls log = new Bl.Logincls();

    public FrmLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnlog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable Dt = log.login(txtid.Text, txtpwd.Text);

        if (Dt.Rows.Count>0)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(this, "تم الدخول", "دخول", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "ليس لك الصلاحيات", "دخول", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }

    private void btncan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to share your code which calls the stored procedure. Are you looking at the right database? Are connecting to the right database?

Comment: you can see now

Comment: Are you able to execute the stored procedure from sql management studio?

Comment: You probably are targeting the wrong instance or you are unable to browse sp's.

Comment: Please post the code of your `UserPassChek` procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this again by adding **schema** name as below. **dbo** is the default schema and check your sp to find correct schema , that you have used.

```
 dt = dal.selectdata("dbo.UserPassChek", param);
```